# azure operation like auto scale ,deploy app via ftp ,and swapping through command line

Tags: azure

I'm new in azure platform
 i have very limited knowledge about it.
 i have to perform some hands on azure platform

1. Auto-scale app service and monitor this application
2. Deploy Web App Through FTP Upload
3. Adding and Swapping Deployment Slots

   how to perform above task from command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the commands are available in the [`Azure CLI documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/?view=azure-cli-latest)

**[Autoscale app service and monitor application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/monitor/autoscale?view=azure-cli-latest)**

```
az monitor autoscale create -g {myrg} --resource {resource-id} --min-count 2 --max-count 5 --count 3 --email-administrator
```

**[`Deploy Web App Through FTP Upload`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/cli-deploy-ftp)**

```
#!/bin/bash

warurl=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure-Samples/html-docs-hello-world/master/index.html
webappname=mywebapp$RANDOM

# Download sample static HTML page
curl $warurl --output index.html

# Create a resource group.
az group create --location westeurope --name myResourceGroup

# Create an App Service plan in `FREE` tier.
az appservice plan create --name myAppServicePlan --resource-group myResourceGroup --sku FREE

# Create a web app.
az webapp create --name $webappname --resource-group myResourceGroup --plan myAppServicePlan

# Get FTP publishing profile and query for publish URL and credentials
creds=($(az webapp deployment list-publishing-profiles --name $webappname --resource-group myResourceGroup \
--query "[?contains(publishMethod, 'FTP')].[publishUrl,userName,userPWD]" --output tsv))

# Use cURL to perform FTP upload. You can use any FTP tool to do this instead. 
curl -T index.html -u ${creds[1]}:${creds[2]} ${creds[0]}/

# Copy the result of the following command into a browser to see the static HTML site.
echo http://$webappname.azurewebsites.net
```

**[Adding and Swapping deployment slots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/deployment/slot?view=azure-cli-latest)**

```
az webapp deployment slot auto-swap --slot
                                    [--auto-swap-slot]
                                    [--disable]
                                    [--ids]
                                    [--name]
                                    [--resource-group]
                                    [--subscription]
```